# Ionic 3 - Add plugins to build.gradle files

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

To link **Firebase** with my **Ionic 3** android app, I need to add these lines to `platforms/android/build.gradle` :

```gradle
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
  }
}
```

and `platforms/android/app/build.gradle` :

```gradle
dependencies {
  // Add this line
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there a way to achieve this without directly editing `build.gradle` files ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following two plugins.  I've used them in the past and seemed to have done the job.

- https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release
- https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release